# click event on <li> element using blazor does not trigger

Tags: blazor

I have the following:

```
<ul class="label-3" role="listbox">
    @foreach (var searchoption in SearchBy.SearchValues)
    {
    <li value="@searchoption.SearchById" @onclick="@(() => LstItemClick(searchoption))">@searchoption.Value</li>
    }
</ul>
```

This all renders fine.

in my CS file (not using an @Code Block)

```
private void LstItemClick(Search e)
{
    Criteria = e.Value;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong.

Comment: I tested your code on my machine and it worked fine.  Are you saying LstItemClick() not being called?

Comment: @JasonD yes, the backend method does not trigger when you click on one of the list items. We are using Microsoft Edge Browser

Comment: "In my CS file" - be clear how that is related to the .razor. It's probably where the error is.

Comment: Look at @JasonD's answer.  If `LstItemClick` is not being called, then the code behind file (the CS file) is not linked correctly to the Razor file.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I added a razor page initially and then removed the` @code` block. I then added a class file giving it the same name as my razor page. Within VS solution explorer, it shows as expected indented and below the razor page.

Comment: Ok, looks right, check your namespaces for both files.

Comment: If the namespace is wrong, I believe the code won't compile.

Comment: @bilpor is it possible for you to post the actual code on Github?  It sounds like you are doing everything right, so I'm not sure how else we can help without being able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't post a complete working example, I built my own and this worked fine on both Chrome and Edge.  When I set a breakpoint in the event handler I can see it is getting called with the correct Value.

**LiClickText.razor**

```
@page "/ClickTest"

@foreach (var searchoption in MySearches)
{
    <li value="@searchoption.SearchById" @onclick="@(() => LstItemClick(searchoption))">@searchoption.Value</li>
}

@code {
    public class Search
    {
        public string SearchById { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    List<Search> MySearches = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MySearches.Add(new Search
        {
            SearchById = "abcde",
            Value = "Item1"
        });
        MySearches.Add(new Search
        {
            SearchById = "fghij",
            Value = "Item2"
        });
    }
}
```

**LiClickTest.razor.cs**

```
public partial class LiClickTest
{
    private void LstItemClick(Search e)
    {
        var Criteria = e.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue was the dropdown section wasn't with the component, I was deliberately keeping it outside of a generic component that we had. I had to create another with the listbox inside then it worked.